# Ruby Sinatra validation returning errors to the view

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Rails dev new to sinatra...I'm trying to do some simple validations.  When I try:

```
validates_presence_of :email, message: "Email cannot be blank."

   @emails.errors.each do |e|
      puts e
    end
```

Sinatra returns

**[: errorI"^Rack::Lint::LintError: Body yielded non-string value [:email, ["Email cannot be blank."]**

How can I extract the error messages from that array, and any further validations I apply to this table.

I've tried `puts e.first` and few other options and i'm getting no where.  Should i do this differently?

Thanks in advance!

```
# app.rb
require "sinatra"
require "Clipboard"
require "sinatra/activerecord"
require 'pony'

#basic auth
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Enter Demo password." do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['censor', 'censor']
end


#options
set :port, 3000

# configure :development do
  set :database, "sqlite3:///exceptDev.db"
# end

#end options


######################
####    MODELS      #
######################

class Emails < ActiveRecord::Base
  #validate fields  
  validates_presence_of :email, message: "Email cannot be blank."
end



######################
####    ROUTES       #
######################

get '/' do
  erb :index
end


get '/contact' do
  #create email record
  @fullname = params[:name].split
  @emails = Emails.create(first_name: @fullname.first, 
                          email: params[:email], 
                          last_name: @fullname.last,
                          msg: params[:msg],
                          postcards: params[:postcards],
                          stickers: params[:stickers]
                          )

  if @emails.save 
    redirect "/", notice: "HYFR!"
  else
    redirect "", errors: "wsdfasdf"
    # @emails.errors.each do |e|
    #   puts e
    # end #errors block
  end #if save
end #contact action
```

Comment: You've not given any Sinatra code, that's code from the model.

Comment: @iain that's the ruby related to the question.

Comment: There's no `validates_presence_of` in Sinatra's code base, so unless you post some Sinatra code, like how you're calling the model, then you've mis-tagged this question.

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Just posted my entire app.rb.  Not sure what the rails api doc will do me in sinatra. Thanks in advance though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Return%20Values):

> The return value of a route block determines at least the response body passed on to the HTTP client, or at least the next middleware in the Rack stack. Most commonly, this is a string

You're trying to pass an array instead of a string. The return types are (again, listed in the docs)

- An Array with three elements: [status (Fixnum), headers (Hash), response body (responds to #each)]
- An Array with two elements: [status (Fixnum), response body (responds to #each)]
- An object that responds to #each and passes nothing but strings to the given block
- A Fixnum representing the status code

If you posted up the code you'd written it'd be easier to show you what to do, but this is basically what's happening.

---

From additional code:

In the route, at the very end of it, try something like this:

```
get '/contact' do
  # other code, then…
```

<del>if @emails.errors</del>

```
  unless @emails.errors?
    haml :show_a_nice_view_to_the_user
  else
    output = @emails.errors.join("; ")
    # log problems…
```

<del>halt 500, output</del>

```
    haml :error_template
  end
end

# in the error_template (or the show_a_nice_view_to_the_user
# it's up to you if you show a special page or not)
- @errors.full_messages.each do |error|
  %p= error
```

Comment: @jahrichie I've added a little bit ot the answer.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! I got an undefined method error on split, but if i remove the split and call to_a, your solution works. Thoughts?

Comment: I've just been looking at http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M001736 and the two methods that I think you'll need are `empty?` and `full_messages`. I'd use `unless @errors.empty?`… as the condition, and pass `@errors` to a template [to render using a block](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_blocks), probably like `- @errors.full_messages.each do |error|` etc.

Comment: I added a bit to the answer, hope it makes sense.